# Android/Linux: Error of failed request: BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)

Tags: android, ubuntu, opengl-es

Getting below error while running android emulator:

```
[2012-11-13 21:27:15 - Emulator] X Error of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
[2012-11-13 21:27:15 - Emulator]   Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
[2012-11-13 21:27:15 - Emulator]   Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
[2012-11-13 21:27:15 - Emulator]   Serial number of failed request:  15
[2012-11-13 21:27:15 - Emulator]   Current serial number in output stream:  16
```

Comment: It's been some time since I play with the android emulator, but I remember something like that happening when I didn't set the memory amount in the device section before starting a project

Comment: Assigned 500 MB, snapshot enabled...still not working

Comment: Do you have an Intel graphics card? If so, check [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/problem-with-the-intel-driver-938020/)

Comment: I have this error when I try Java FX with Netbeans (8 on Debian)

Answer (score 2):

Some old intel graphics card have this problem, I am facing this problem with intel 82865G graphic and ubuntu 12.04, one work around for this is to launch emulator from command prompt, then it will use software renderer, go to android-sdks/tools directory and type: emulator-arm -avd your_avd, Using command line I am able to work

Comment: In my installed version of Android Studio (1.4.1) it's possible to uncheck "Use Host GPU" for a particular virtual device in the AVD Manager to use software rendering instead, which by the way was a successful workaround for me.