# Android emulator error: std::bad_alloc

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I'm using Eclipse Juno and the Android emulator (SDK Tools 21.1) and I'm having this error a lot of times (well, two or three times in 6 hours):

```
[2013-03-22 11:41:19 - Emulator] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
[2013-03-22 11:41:19 - Emulator]   what():  std::bad_alloc
[2013-03-22 11:41:19 - Emulator] 
[2013-03-22 11:41:19 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an      unusual way.
[2013-03-22 11:41:19 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I've googled it but it seems to be an C++ error. I don't know if it's an error of my application or if is an error of Eclipse or the emulator. (The LogCat does not show any error).

Comment: sounds like an emulator issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorry my reputation is not high enough, this should be a comment, since it is not a real solution.

I'm having the same issues, but it stops when I disable 'Use Host GPU'. I think it must be an error in of the emulator, since I can also generate the issue when I play around in the emulator (without using my own app).

Comment: Oh thanks. I'm using 'Use Host GPU' too. I supposse my app is OK, but I wonder if more people have this issue (google it and no answer related to Android).

Comment: Yeah, and on the device there are no issues whatsoever. I'm keeping an eye on this thread for a real solution ;-)

Comment: Same problem, disabling Host GPU helped.

Comment: Thats's it! Disabling Host GPU problem disappeared! Thanks for your time!

Comment: If I disable the Host GPU then how am I suppsed to improve the slow emulator.

Comment: @user285oo6 As I said, this is not a real solution in my eyes. That said, I ditched the emulator a long time ago and I am using http://www.genymotion.com/ now --> much much faster and more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by RobinDeCroon, I only have this issue when using "Use Host GPU". From 
[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364118/android-linux-error-of-failed-request-badalloc-insufficient-resources-for-ope), it's possibly a bug/problem with older Intel graphics cards

Answer (score 0):

I Had the exactly same error message while using Android Studio and Fixed it by changing the Boot option from Quick Boot to Cold Boot. In Android Studio you can go into Tools > Android > AVD Manager > Edit (The Pencil) > Show Advanced Settings > And changed from Quick Boot to Cold Boot.

I don't know how to do that only with only the emulator, but this may be a clue of how to solve this.